# Macbook M1 Monterey – USB Audio dropouts Core Audio

Tags: macos, console, console-application, core-audio, macos-monterey

I am trying to solve my USB audio problems on 2022 M1 MacBook Pro 14" with 16GB RAM/latest Monterey connected to an external DAC via USB which results in irregular audio dropouts. Audio gets muted for about 1 sec after some time using the MacBook and gets more often after some usage, sometimes multiple times in a minute. Internal audio seems to work fine. It is independent on the DAC i use (already tried another one).

Every time audio is muted I get the following error message (with a new timestamp) from CAReportingService (Core Audio) in Console.app:

`10:11:30.424212+0200   CAReportingService  flushMessagesWithCompletion: flush failed with error '<private>'`

I already tried this:

1. repaired UserPermissions
2. deleted Audio Plugins

Does anyone have an idea to solve this issue? Is it a hardware or software issue? Thanks

Comment: There might be useful information in that error log, but macos has censored it (it's marked `private`). Install a profile to fix this and see if that gets you useful info: https://www.cmdsec.com/unified-logs-enable-private-data

Comment: Tested with updated VLC, Apple Music and Audirvana (old Version 3.5) – all the same…

Comment: Nope – Firefox and WebRTC aren't the cause for the problem… investigated further on this with activity monitor and found systemstats using 20GB RAM on my 16GB M1 MBP… Terminal `sudo killall systemstats` did the job to close the memory leak for the moment. May be this helps…

Comment: But: Firefox is a memory hog – with many tabs open memory usage exceeds easily some gigs (look for "FirefoxCP Isolated Web Content"  in activity monitor). So it cured the problem only for the moment because closing firefox freed some memory.

Comment: There is apparently a bug with `CAReportingService` under high memory usage. See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253960632